# Retrieving selected fields from database using Hibernate

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql

I'm retrieving a list of rows with selected fields from Oracle database using Hibernate. The retrieval is made by the following method in one of the DAOs in my application.

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public List<Object[]> getOldFileName(String []ids)
{
    int len=ids.length;
    Long longType[]=new Long[len];

    for(int i=0;i<len;i++)
    {
        longType[i]=Long.valueOf(ids[i]);
    }
    return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("select catId, catImage from Category where catId in(:id)").setParameterList("id", longType).list();
}
```

Here I'm fetching two fields `categoryId` and `categoryImage` as listed in the given HQL query based on the `catId` supplied as an array of `String[]` as a method parameter via Spring. It works fine and there is no question about it.

But regarding my requirements, retrieving `catId` again is completely unnecessary and I would like to remove `catId` from the list of fields in the query something simply like the following.

```
select catImage from Category where catId in(:id)
```

If I try to execute this query then the following call to the preceding method inside the Spring controller class,

```
String temp[]=request.getParameter("setDel").split(",");
List<Object[]> oldFileNames = categoryService.getOldFileName(temp); 
//Invokes the preceding method in DAO.
```

causes the following exception to be thrown,

> java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.String cannot be cast to
>   [Ljava.lang.Object;

The exception message indicates that `java.lang.String` cannot be cast to an array of Objects - `Object[]`. It appears that the HQL statement attempts to get only a single value of type String instead of retrieving `List<Object[]>`.

I just want to delete files which are stored in a directory after retrieving their names from the database and mentioning of `catId` in the list of fields in HQL is completely unnecessary.

Why do I need to add `catId` in the list of fields of the HQL statement in this scenario?

Comment: Quite simple. The method `getOldFileName(String []ids)` attempts to return `List<String>` instead of returning `List<Object[]>` as there is only one field `catImage` of type `String` in this query - `select catImage from Category where catId in(:id)`. Kept thinking for a long time but could not figure out this simple thing before asking the question. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return type for the list should be List.  When only one column comes back hibernate does not put the result into and Object[]

Comment: Thank you. I suddenly realized the issue that I had been overseeing  for a long time and couldn't figure it out before I posted the question as I commented out below the question section.